# Adding Attiny to Arduino IDE - attiny\variants\platform.txt file missing

Tags: arduino-ide, attiny

I followed [this guide](http://www.instructables.com/id/Programming-an-ATTiny13A-using-Arduino-servo-int/step3/Programming/) to program AtTiny using Arduino as ISP. The problem is that it has some file missing:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\...\arduino-1.6.8\hardware\attiny\variants\platform.txt
```

The attiny directory is [clone of this repository](https://github.com/tekstop/attiny/tree/Arduino1). How do I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Open the "Preferences" dialog in the Arduino IDE.
- Click on the symbol next to "Additional Board Manager URLs"

  [image: Additional Board Manager URLs]
- Paste the following into the box (possibly on a new line under any existing URLs), then click OK.

  ```
  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/damellis/attiny/ide-1.6.x-boards-manager/package_damellis_attiny_index.json
  ```

  [image: Add board URL]

  Note that you can click on the circled link for a list of boards. This will open in your web browser. You may have to switch to your browser to notice it.

[image: List of unofficial boards]

- Click OK to close the Preferences dialog box.
- In the Tools menu / Board select the Boards Manager:

  [image: Boards Manager]
- Scroll down until you see the Attiny entry (or the one for the board you want), click on it to select it, and then click "Install".

  [image: Install Attiny]
- Once done, close the Board Manager dialog box.
- You should now be able to select Attiny from the Boards menu:

  [image: Select Attiny]
- Now in the Tools menu you can select which Attiny you want to use:

  [image: Which Attiny]
- Notice you can also select the appropriate clock speed in an adjacent menu item.
- To program the Attiny you will need a suitable ISP (In System Programmer) such as the AVRISP programmer, or the USBtinyISP programmer.

Answer (score 1):

The way of adding boards has changed in the newer version.

Try finding a tutorial for 1.6, or download the older [1.0 version](http://arduino.cc/download_handler.php?f=/arduino-1.0.6-windows.exe).

Comment: I tried to find up to date tutorials and what I found is linked in my question. I think this answer would better qualify as a comment since it's like link-only, but without the link...

Comment: The tutorial was using version 1.0, while you are using 1.6.8. That is why you are getting the error. So that is an answer. PS The tutorial is more than 4 years old, and the github repo is from 2011.